# Why does applying the min() function on a map() object render it useless for further operations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, min

When I apply `min()` on `map()`, I get the below result for this particular code:

```
a = map(int, input().split())

print(min(a))

for i in a:
    print(i)
```

**For the input:**
5 7 10 5 15

I get the result:

```
5
```

which is the minimum, but it doesn't execute the `for` loop.

But if I write:

```
a = map(int, input().split())

for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Then for the same input, it executes the `for` loop, and I get the result:

```
5
7
10
5
15
```

Why using the `min()` function before the `for` loop, is stopping the `for` loop from executing?

Comment: you can read here about generators and yield, a very good explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do

Comment: @mackostya probably should note, `map` objects are *iterators* not *generators* (although all generators are iterators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = map(int, input().split())
```

this command returns an iterator object. Furthermore, to work on any iterator internally, `next` is used by many functions internally. And once there is no `next` output or no `next` object, then it exits (see `__next__` implementation for more).

In case 1. the `min` function has used this property and traversed through this iterator and returned the minimum value, and in that `next` point to none, so for loop is not working there.

While in case 2. `next` object still points out to the first element of the `map` object, and thus to run iterations on this object is possible, that's why for loop work there.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2, *map()* returned a *list* and in that environment the behaviour that you were expecting would have occurred.

However, in Python 3, *map()* returns a *map* object which is an iterator.

When you pass an iterator to a function such as *min()* it will be consumed - i.e. any subsequent attempts to acquire data from it will fail (not with any error but as if the iterator has been naturally exhausted).

To get the desired behaviour in the OP's code just do this:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use map function in python, it returns a generator.

then when you call it with min function, it iterates over that generator and makes the generator internally point to the end of the iterable object.

then you try to reiterate on that generator, but it's already lost its initial "index" and points to the end of the iterable object

Answer (score 1):

What you passed into [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=dir#min) is the result of a [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=dir#map), which is a generator. Its values are consumed by the `min()` function before the `for` loop gets the chance to consume them.

If you consume the generator and put its values into a list again, you can iterate as many times as you want.

```py
a = list(map(int, input().split()))

print(min(a))

for i in a:
    print(i)
```